# Use mangled Rust functions from Rust dynamic library

Tags: rust, dynamic-library

### Edit Note

Since Rust (ver.: 1.42) still doesn't have a stable [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface), it is recommended to use `extern` (which is currently equivalent to `extern "C"` (may change in the future)) Otherwise, it may be necessary to recompile the libraries.

[This article](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/external-blocks.html#abi) explains how to change the [calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention).

---

The goal is to be able to functions with mangled names (which would allow the coexistence of functions from different modules/namespaces that have the same identifiers) inside the crate that uses the library.

I have noticed that Rust (ver.: 1.42) automatically assumes that function identifiers of the exported functions are ***not*** mangled.

At the moment I can successfully link it and use it when using `#[no_mangle]` and `#[export_name="..."]` on the functions.

I am using the `stable-x86_64-windows-pc-msvc` toolchain.

---

### Working example

**rslib/lib.rs:**

```rust
#[no_mangle] /* Exports it as "func" */
pub extern fn func() { ... }
```

**app/main.rs:**

```rust
#[link(name="rslib.dll", kind="dylib")]
extern { fn func(); }

fn main() {
    unsafe { func(); }
}
```

This compiles and runs without a problem.

---

### Not working example

**rslib/lib.rs:**

```
pub extern fn func() { ... }
```

Using the same "app/main.rs" causes the linking to fail with:
`error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_func referenced in function _ZN8rust_app4main17h52189e261ef80b93E`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Manual solution

The solution I have come up with is manually placing `#[link_name="..."]` on the functions in the `extern` block. This way it is possible to also have modules that use imported functions.

*Note: Could possibly be done with macros!*

**rslib/lib.rs:**

```rust
pub mod foo {
    #[export_name="foo_func"] /* Also possible to append some identification for different parameters if desired */
    pub extern fn func() { ... }
}

#[export_name="func"]
pub extern fn func() { ... }
```

**app/main.rs:**

```rust
mod foo {
    #[link(name="rslib.dll", kind="dylib")]
    extern {
        #[link_name="foo_func"]
        pub fn func();
    }
}

#[link(name="rslib.dll", kind="dylib")]
extern {
    #[link_name="_func"]
    pub fn func();
}

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        func();
        foo::func();
    }
}
```